# Rendering specific fields multiple times in Django model form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am learning django and have encountered a challenge. I have a model in which I want to render specific fields multiple times depending on how much the user wants to fill in, while rest of the model fields remain the same. Below is an example model. I want to render the model form in such a way that the fields `'building'` and `'tour_date'` can be repeated as many times as required while `'client_name'` and `'client_email'` remain the same.

I looked at `inlineformset_factory` but I think it needs a parent model. I don't think it serves my purpose although I would love to have some of its features like `'extra'` and `'can_delete'`. The saved records have to be saved as new rows in the `'Tour'` table.

Another challenge I am facing with the below example is that the 'building' field has to be a drop-down. I have provided the forms.py below for reference.

How can I write a view and render the two fields `'building'` and `'tour_date'` multiple times in the same form in Django 3.0? Requesting some assistance and guidance.

models.py:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
building = models.CharField(max_length=255)
tour_date = models.DateField()
...

class Meta:
    managed = True
    unique_together = ('name', 'building')
```

forms.py:

```
class TourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    building = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select,
        queryset=Country.objects.filter(city='ABC'),
        required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'building','tour_date']
```

views.py:

```
def add_tours(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('tours-browse')
    else:
        form = TourForm()
    template = 'data/tours_add.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is using a ManytoMany relationship or manytoone depending on your application, it will be a hell lot of work but its worth it, see more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: How to I render the fields multiple times in my form? Right now, it is giving me an option to enter the values for 'building' and 'tour_date' only once before I submit. How can I make the form render these fields multiple times like in inlineformset_factory?

Comment: Now once you have this use Jquery + Html to add fields, so you user click on a link say "Add Another" and they will pile, you can then use views.py to code how the actions are handled as opposed to using forms.py - Frontend will be something like this http://demos.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/ its not a complete solution but just to give you an idea

Comment: Thank you, I will explore the link you shared.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a model in which I want to render specific fields multiple times depending on how much the user wants to fill in, while rest of the model fields remain the same.

This is not how it works. Database fields are atomic - they only hold one single value. If you want an indefinite number of values, you use a related model with either a one to many (foreign key) or many to many relationship. IOW you want a 'TourDate' and a 'Building' models, both with either a ForeignKey or ManyToMany relationship on 'Tour'. And then you'll be able to use formsets for those related models.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into how to modify models accordingly.